# PHP : calculation of date and time cannot understand the output before or after in minutes

Tags: php, laravel

My code is as below for difference between two date and times

```
<?php
$checkin = new DateTime('2022-06-07 00:30:00');
$starttime = new DateTime('2022-06-07 00:10:00');

$interval = $checkin->diff($starttime);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%i minutes');
echo $elapsed;
?>
```

output : 20 mins

**My scenarios are as below**

- When User checkin to the location before 15min
- When User checkin to the location after ontime / or 15mins

But how can i identify the user has checking in before or after in minutes. If i reverse $checkin and $starttime i see the same output. Please suggest

Comment: `if( $checkin > $starttime ) { ... }` Also see `invert` property on [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert) and the `r` and `R` flags on [`DateInterval::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Comment: @Sammitch: Please explain in detail

Comment: Uhhh... `if()` is a logical construct, and `>` is a comparison operator that returns `true` if the left operand is larger than the right operand.

Comment: @sammitch : before you have just added some condition and left so i have asked in detailed. Now i understand with updated comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are in Laravel, here it uses [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) dates, use that advantage.

```
$checkIn = Carbon::parse('2022-06-07 00:30:00');
$startTime = Carbon::parse('2022-06-07 00:10:00');
```

Now you get a lot of helper methods, easier comparisions with greater or lesser than. Syntaxic shorted to `lt()` or `gt()`, secondly use `lte()` and `gte()` to get greater than equal.

For the checkin before start time, you can use your date diff combined with `lte()` and you will get the logic you want.

```
private function isCheckedInEarly($startTime, $checkIn): bool
{
    return $checkIn->lte($startTime) && $checkIn->diffInMinutes($startTime) > 20;
}
```

The second part which was worded a little confusing, you can use the same methodology, to get the logic.

```
private function onTimeOrFiftenMinutesLate($startTime, $checkIn): bool
{
    return $checkIn->gte($startTime) && $checkIn->diffInMinutes($startTime) <= 15;
}
```